# Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|^4}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, dispersive-pde

Let $f(x) = e^{-\alpha\pi|x|^4}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\alpha > 0$ is a constant. I know that, taking $g(x) = e^{-\pi \alpha|x|^2}$, we get
$$\hat{g}(\xi) = \alpha^{-n/2}e^{-\pi|\xi|^2/\alpha}.$$
Although the functions $f$ and $g$ sounds similar, to calculate $\hat{f}$ sounds trickier. In fact, I have heard that there's no representation with elementary functions for $\hat{f}$.

**The context**: I have the integral,
$$g(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i \xi \cdot y - |y|^4} dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{- |y|^4} e^{-i \xi \cdot y } dy = \hat{f}(\xi),$$
where $f(x) = e^{-|x|^4}$.  This is why I'm trying to calculate that Fourier Transform.

Anyone know how to rewrite that Fourier transform in terms of non elementary functions? I would be very thankful for any reference with this things.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{\omega ^4}{256}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \omega ^2
   \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \, _0F_2\left(;\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{\omega
   ^4}{256}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$$